# use function doesn't work in a if else statement PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the `browscap-php` in a if else statement in `Apache` & `PHP 5+`. I'm using the [Browscap.php](https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php/blob/master/src/phpbrowscap/Browscap.php) file like this below as a example.

**Working example:**

```
<?php 
   require 'Browscap.php';
   use phpbrowscap\Browscap;

   if ($newdata == "1") { 
       $current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();
   } else {

   }

?>
```

**Not working example:**

```
<?php 

   if ($newdata == "1") { 
       require 'Browscap.php';
       use phpbrowscap\Browscap;
       $current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();
   } else {
   // do not load anything dealing with browscap
   }
?>
```

The working example works fine but the second I place the `use` function in the if else statement it doesn't work. I don't want `browscap` loaded when I don't need to check for that information. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Pekka웃 it causes a `500 Internal server error` and I have error reporting on and it doesn't show anything.

Comment: You don't actually need the `use phpbrowscap\Browscap` anyway. You could just call the fully qualified namespace when you want to instantiate that class.

Comment: `use` doesn't load anything

Comment: In PHP, a 500 error always means "go look in your error log". Crank up `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and show onscreen with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @PeeHaa yes but I don't want to `include` the file either when it's no needed.

Comment: If you get a 500, then errors are going to the `error.log`, can you check that out? (And/or activate `display_errors` so you see errors on screen) /Edit: ah, Michael beat me to it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski did that already.

Comment: But the problem as you said is the `use` statement... @AbbyE

Comment: @AbbyE Any 500 error generated by PHP (as opposed to something caused by Apache or other) _will_ have an associated error message, and `display_errors` should cause that to be shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> The use keyword must be declared in the **outermost scope** of a file (the
>   global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the
>   importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it **cannot be
>   block scoped**.

(my emphasis)

Comment: I understand now, I'm just going to use the included in the if else statement and then put the `use` function on the outer cope of the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the use statement above the if. The use statements does not load anything. The require statement is the one that loads the file, and you can keep that in the if.